# Como utilizar String para sair da repetição while?

Tags: java

Olá fiz um código para calcular as médias de notas. Da forma que fiz abaixo ele funciona normalmente, porém quero sair da repetição While digitando "sair".
O que tenho alterar no código?

[Calculo média de notas](https://github.com/pliniopereira10/resolucao-desafios-java/blob/main/desafios-no-curso/controle/CalculoMediaNotas.java)

```
// Programa calcula a média de notas inseridas
// CalculoMediaNotas.java

package controle;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalculoMediaNotas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        /*
         * O programa tem finalidade de calcular média de notas de uma turma. Conforme é
         * solicitado para inserir a nota. Programa vai armazenando elas, posteriormente
         * quando solicitado para sair, exibe o resultado das médias.
         */
        
        // Prompt de captura
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        // Variáveis
        double media;
        double nota = 0;
        double total = 0;

        int quantidadeDeNotas = 0;
        
                
        // Menu de exibição
        System.out.println("****\t****\t****\t****\t****");
        System.out.println("||\tCálculo Média De Notas\t  ||");
        System.out.println("****\t****\t****\t****\t****");
        
        System.out.println();
        
        System.out.println("Para visualizar o resultado e sair.");
        System.out.println("Digite \"-1\".\n");
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  ||");
        System.out.println("****\t****\t****\t****\t****");
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  ||");
        
        // Início da estrutura de repetição
        while(nota != -1) {
            
            System.out.print("Informe uma nota: ");
            nota = teclado.nextDouble();
                        
            // Início da condição
            if(nota >= 0 && nota <=10) {
                
                total = total + nota;   // Equivale a total += nota
                quantidadeDeNotas++;
                
            } else if(nota > 10) {
                
                System.out.println("Por favor, \ninsira uma nota válida:");
                System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  ||");
                                
            } // fim da condição
                
        } // fim estrutura de repetição
    
        // Cálculo da média
        media = total / quantidadeDeNotas;
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  ||");
        System.out.println("****\t****\t****\t****\t****");
        System.out.printf("Foram digitadas %d notas.%nA média das notas é %.2f",
                quantidadeDeNotas, media);
        System.out.println("\t  ||");
        System.out.println("****\t****\t****\t****\t****");

        teclado.close(); // fim classe Scanner

    } // fim método main

} // fim classe CalculoMediaNotas
```

Comment: Coloque o código relevante na pergunta para ser possível de analisá-lo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adicione antes do fim do while.

```java
System.out.println("Deseja sair? digite sair");
            String s = teclado.next();
            if (s.equals("sair") || s.equalsIgnoreCase("sair")) {
                nota = -1;
            }
```

lembrando que seu codigo pode ser melhorado, talvez possa haver uma solução melhor, mas resolve.